# MYSQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s) - Nested Case statement

Tags: mysql, case, code

I have written the below query with nested case statements. The syntax checks out but when I run it I receive error code 1241: Operand should contain only 1 column(s). I have attempted to remove the parenthesis from the SELECT statements but it does not help and indicates there is a syntax error.

This query is intended to select a data subset based on current time. The first case selects data from today's first shift. The second nested case determines if the current time the night portion of second shift (Between now and midnight 2nd shift) or the early morning portion of second shift between  midnight and 4:30. If it is after midnight then date from today and today-1 is selected. Any ideas?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN current_time() BETWEEN CAST('6:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('16:30:00' AS TIME)
    THEN
        (SELECT infeedweight, outfeedweight, yield, time_stamp, num_checks_passed, num_checks_failed,TIME(time_stamp) 
            FROM workers_totals
            WHERE time_stamp >= curdate())
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN (current_time() BETWEEN CAST('16:30:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME))
            THEN 
                 (SELECT infeedweight, outfeedweight, yield, time_stamp, num_checks_passed, num_checks_failed,TIME(time_stamp)
                 FROM workers_totals
                 WHERE time_stamp >= CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 16:30:00') AS DATETIME)  and CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 23:59:59') AS DATETIME))
            ELSE
                 (SELECT infeedweight, outfeedweight, yield, time_stamp, num_checks_passed, num_checks_failed,TIME(time_stamp) 
                 FROM workers_totals
                 WHERE (time_stamp >= CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 00:00:00') AS DATETIME)  and CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 04:59:59') AS DATETIME))
                 OR (time_stamp >= CAST(CONCAT(curdate()-1,' 16:30:00') AS DATETIME)  and CAST(CONCAT(curdate()-1,' 23:59:59') AS DATETIME)))
            END
    END
```

Comment: At which statement that syntax error is issued particularly. What don't you understand why it's issued? Can you reproduce it with a less complex example?

Comment: The `CASE` expression must return a single value, not a result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` in MySQL can either be a statement, or an expression.

Since your `CASE` statement is in a `SELECT` list, it's being treated as an expression. As an expression, it should return a single value. You're trying to return multiple columns (and, presumably multiple rows).

Presumably, you want to use `CASE` as a statement, without the `SELECT` in front, so that just one of your three `SELECT` statements is executed:

```
CASE WHEN current_time() BETWEEN CAST('6:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('16:30:00' AS TIME)
     THEN 
          SELECT infeedweight, outfeedweight, yield, time_stamp, num_checks_passed, num_checks_failed,TIME(time_stamp) 
            FROM workers_totals
           WHERE time_stamp >= curdate()
     WHEN (current_time() BETWEEN CAST('16:30:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME)
        THEN
             SELECT infeedweight, outfeedweight, yield, time_stamp, num_checks_passed, num_checks_failed,TIME(time_stamp)
               FROM workers_totals
              WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 16:30:00') AS DATETIME) and CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 23:59:59') AS DATETIME)
     ELSE
             SELECT infeedweight, outfeedweight, yield, time_stamp, num_checks_passed, num_checks_failed,TIME(time_stamp) 
               FROM workers_totals
              WHERE (time_stamp BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) and CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 04:59:59') AS DATETIME))
                 OR (time_stamp BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT(curdate()-1,' 16:30:00') AS DATETIME) and CAST(CONCAT(curdate()-1,' 23:59:59') AS DATETIME))
END CASE
```

Note that the `CASE` statement is terminated with `END CASE` instead of just `END`.

Also, I've condensed your code to use one `CASE` statement instead of two nested ones (you can have multiple `WHEN` branches with `CASE`), and changed your timestamp comparisons to check if the value is `BETWEEN` the two dates you supply, instead of `timestamp >= dateX AND dateY`.

You should double-check your `time_stamp` boundaries - for times between midnight and 6AM, you're cutting off anything with a timestamp later than today at 5AM.

Finally, note that this can only be used in a stored program.

I believe you could do this as a single `SELECT` statement, without needing a `CASE` at all:

```
SELECT infeedweight, outfeedweight, yield, time_stamp, num_checks_passed, num_checks_failed,TIME(time_stamp) 
  FROM workers_totals
 WHERE (    current_time() < CAST('6:00:00' AS TIME)
        AND time_stamp >= CAST(CONCAT(curdate()-1,' 16:30:00') AS DATETIME)
        AND time_stamp <=CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 04:59:59') AS DATETIME)
       )
    OR (    current_time() >= CAST('6:00:00' AS TIME)
        AND current_time() < CAST('16:30:00' AS TIME)
        AND time_stamp >= curdate()
       )
    OR (    current_time() >= CAST('16:30:00' AS TIME)
        AND time_stamp >= CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 16:30:00')
        AND time_stamp <= CAST(CONCAT(curdate(),' 23:59:59') AS DATETIME)
       )
;
```

I've tweaked your `current_time()` checks, to try to make sure that all times are covered, and fall uniquely into one range or another. You'll want to validate that this works as intended.

NOTE: All code is untested.

Comment: Thank you RDFozz! I did not realize it was being treated as an expression. Thanks for the training and the WHERE based SELECT statement. It ran like a dream after two small tweaks.

Comment: @MilfordTechnologyGuy did this resolve for you? When I start my query with CASE, it gives me error.